# Find all CSS rules that apply to an element (2018)

Tags: javascript, css

*I was wondering how can I find all CSS rules that apply to an element.
All the solutions that I've found so far either*

1. use CSSStyleSheet.cssRules or CSSStyleSheet.rules properties. Doesn't work, because as of Chrome 64 you'll need to use a local development server to test functionality that depends on the CSS Object Model.
2. use getComputedStyles(), which is full of garbage like default/incorrect values and no `@media` or `pseudo` classes.

I want to copy an element from one site to another. I use Node.cloneNode(true) to clone the element. When I move the element to the other site, the styles inherited from the clone's classeNames and id don't exist anymore. That's why I want to find all CSS rules that apply to the element, so I can "reapply" them on the other site.

With window.getComputedStyles e.g. the width of the element is fixed to an exact amount of pixels, even if it was originally dynamic, :hover classes are ignored, all "sub"-classes like 'border-right', 'border-left' are defined even if the original div only had the short-hand property 'border' defined

How may I find all **CSS Rules** that apply to an element?

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to build? Why do you want to find all CSS rules that apply to an element?

Comment: You can see it from Google chrome inspector..

Comment: I want to copy an element from one site to another. I use Node.cloneNode(true) to clone the element. When I move the element to the other site, the styles inherited from the clone's classes and id don't exist anymore. That's why I want to find all CSS rules that apply to the element, so I can "reapply" them on the other site. With window.getComputedStyles e.g. the width of the element is fixed to an exact amount of pixels, even if it was originally dynamic, :hover classes are ignored, all "sub"-classes like border-right, border-left are defined even if the original div only had border defined

Comment: Doubt there is any trivial way to do this